# Why can't Console.WriteLine determine my type? in F#

Tags: types, f#, function-composition

Here's my code:

```
open System

let places = [ ("Grandchester", 552);
               ("Cambridge", 117900);
               ("Prague", 1188126); ]

let statusByPopulation = function
                            | n when n > 1000000 -> "City"
                            | n when n > 50000   -> "Town"
                            | _                  -> "Village"

System.Console.WriteLine ( places |> List.map (fun (_, population) -> statusByPopulation population)) 

let print x = 
    Console.WriteLine (List.map (fun (_, population) -> statusByPopulation population) x) // what I'm trying to do

let something (x:(string * int) list) = 
    List.map (fun (_, population) -> statusByPopulation population) x; // checking what kinf of type it returns

let print: (string * int) list -> unit = 
    Console.WriteLine << List.map (fun (_, population) -> statusByPopulation population) // what I'm not allowed to do

System.Console.ReadKey () |> ignore
```

I wanted to get familiar with the way the function composition operator worked, but for some reason F# can't find the best possible overload for the function...

In the example where I explicitly state the parameter, it sets the type to be `val print : x:('a * int) list -> unit`, so I explicitly set the type in the function with the composition operator `<<` hoping I'd get the correct result... I didn't...

I then made the function `something` with an explicitly declared type for the parameter, just to see what it'd return... It returns this: `val something : x:(string * int) list -> string list`

So it most definitely returns a type... a list of strings, which I know Console.WriteLine is capable of printing... So why does it tell me it can't determine the overload?

Comment: Type inference works left-to-right; use pipelining (`|>`) to invoke `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: I didn't want to use pipelining, I want to save the one parameter...

`f << g = f(g(x)) = g(x) |> f`

Comment: I've no idea what you mean. What's wrong with `x |> List.map (fun (_, population) -> statusByPopulation population) |> Console.WriteLine`? (Or more succinctly, `x |> List.map (snd >> statusByPopulation) |> Console.WriteLine`?)

Comment: what's wrong is the fact that long code is hard to maintain why do `let f a = snd a |> someFunc` or `let f a = someFunc(snd a)` when you can do `let f = snd >> someFunc`?

Comment: I'm posting a comment rather than answer because I don't want to rationalize; just thought I'd offer a painless workaround.

Comment: the 'painless workaround' doesn't answer the question, I'm aware I can do it your way, but I want to know why my way doesn't work...

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the question, that's why I didn't post an answer. Picky, picky...

Comment: But you're right about the order of evaluation it seems... when I turn it around, putting the `List.map` on the left then do `>>` and then drop the `Console.WriteLine` on the right, it no longer complains... is there an answer as to why it complains, other than it's just the order of evaluation?

Comment: Console.WriteLine has many overloads, type inference works from left to right and top to bottom, so if you put the Console.WriteLine on the left, it don't know which overload you want, when you turn it around, it know you want 'string'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type inference in F# works from the left to the right - this means that the compiler uses information available earlier in the program to determine types of expressions later in the program (this is a slight simplification, but it is the general idea).

So in your code, when you write:

```
Console.WriteLine << List.map (fun (_, population) -> statusByPopulation population)
```

.. the compiler does not propagate the information about the type of function input through the `List.map` call back to the `WriteLine` call. This also explains why forward chaining and composition are generally more useful in F#. The following works:

```
List.map (fun (_, population) -> statusByPopulation population) >> Console.WriteLine
```

To get your original code working, you could provide some minimal amount of information that is needed to determine that the right `WriteLine` overload is the one taking `object`. If you tell the compiler that it needs to take a list of something, then it can choose the right overload:

```
(Console.WriteLine:list<_> -> unit) << List.map (fun (_, population) -> 
    statusByPopulation population)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the answer I needed

Comment: And it's basically what @ildjarn said in his comments above.